# Trying to send the file link to mail but only get one file

Tags: php

Trying to send the file link to mail but only get one file. How can I take all file links and send?

```
public function uploadpath() {
    $this->load->library('upload');

    // If files are selected to upload 
    if (!empty($_FILES['files']['name']) && count(array_filter($_FILES['files']['name'])) > 0) {
        $filesCount = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {
            $_FILES['file']['name'] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['type'] = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['error'] = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['size'] = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];

            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/AddmissionDocument';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|jpg|jpeg|JPEG';
            $config['max_size'] = 0;
            $config['max_width'] = 0;
            $config['max_height'] = 0;
            
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            
            // Upload file to server 
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')){        
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $file=array($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]);
               return $file;     
            }
        }
    }
}
    $files = $this->uploadpath();
    $this->sending($files);
    $this->session->set_userdata(array('idf' => $fid, 'idL' => $result, 'StudentN' => $e, 'course' => $b));
    $this->sucessdata();
}

public function sending($files) {
    $ADMN = $this->session->userdata('ADMISSIONNO');
    $MOE = $this->session->userdata('modeofedu');
    $CC = $this->session->userdata('Course');
    $LCQ = $this->session->userdata('LastQualifiedCourse');
    $UB = $this->session->userdata('UniversityBoard');
    $SN = $this->session->userdata('studentname');
    $DOB = $this->session->userdata('dob');
    $G = $this->session->userdata('gender');
    $OCC = $this->session->userdata('Occupation');
    $FN = $this->session->userdata('FatherName');
    $MN = $this->session->userdata('MotherName');
    $NFS = $this->session->userdata('NameofSpouse');
    $SCC = $this->session->userdata('scountryCode');
    $SMN = $this->session->userdata('sMobileNo');
    $FCC = $this->session->userdata('fcountryCode');
    $FMN = $this->session->userdata('fMobileNo');
    $NCC = $this->session->userdata('ncountryCode');
    $NMN = $this->session->userdata('nMobileNo');
    $N = $this->session->userdata('Nationality');
    $NIDT = $this->session->userdata('Nidtype');
    $NIDN = $this->session->userdata('Nidnumber');
    $PASNO = $this->session->userdata('PassportNumber');
    $EMID = $this->session->userdata('EmiratesId');
    $EMAID = $this->session->userdata('Email');
    $ADD = $this->session->userdata('Address');
    $NADD = $this->session->userdata('NAddress');
    $NADDC = $this->session->userdata('NAddressCity');
    $NADDS = $this->session->userdata('NAddressState');

    $subject = "Application Form Submitted by" . $SN;

    $message = "-----------------------------------------------------------------
 ADMISSION NO      :  $ADMN
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 Mode of Education : $MOE
 Course            : $CC
 Student Name      : $SN
 Date of Birth     : $DOB
 Gender            : $G
 Occupation        : $OCC
 Father Name       : $FN
 Mother Name       : $MN
 Name of Spouse    : $NFS
 Mobile No         : $SCC -$SMN 
 Mobile No         : $FCC -$FMN
 Mobile No         : $NCC -$NMN
 Nationality       : $N
 National ID       : $NIDT    Type ID Number  : $NIDN
 Passport Number   : $PASNO
 Emirates Id       : $EMID
 Email             : $EMAID
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 Address in UAE    : $ADD
-----------------------------------------------------------------
           Permanent Address 
       
 Door No/Lane/Town : $NADD 
 City              : $NADDC
 State             : $NADDS
-----------------------------------------------------------------
$files

";
        $config = array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smpt_host' => 'mail.maseducationuae.com',
            'smpt_port' => '465',
            'smpt_user' => '',
            'smpt_pass' => '',
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'charset' => 'utf-8',
            'wordwrap' => 'TRUE'
        );
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("/r/n");
        $this->email->from('Web Application Form');
        $this->email->to('info@maseducationuae.com');
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
        
        $this->email->send(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within the `uploadPath()` function. In that function the for loop is running for the `$_FILES['files']` array, but the function returns on the first iteration with the first file here,

```php
...
// Upload file to server 
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')){        
    return false;
}
else {
    $file=array($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]);
   return $file;     
}
```

To get all the files, initialize an array `$myFiles` before the `for` loop, then populate the array instead of returning from the for loop and finally return the array from outside the for loop.

```php
public function uploadpath() {
    $this->load->library('upload');

    // initialize empty array
    $myFiles = [];

    // If files are selected to upload 
    if (!empty($_FILES['files']['name']) && count(array_filter($_FILES['files']['name'])) > 0) {
        $filesCount = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {
            // ...
            // ...
            
            // Upload file to server 
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')){        
                // do not append in $myFiles array here.
            } else {
               // append in $myFiles array here.
               $file=array($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]);
               $myFiles[] = $file;
            }
        }
    }

    return $myFiles;
}
```

Now you should have an array of files in here,

```php
$files = $this->uploadpath();
```